# Where to find dotTrace after installation on Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dottrace

I have installed JetBrains dotTrace ( https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ ) on Windows 8.1 Pro. Installation has been completed successfully.

Now how to open dotTrace interface? I did search in Start Menu but couldn't find. I searched by "dottrace" and "jetbrains" keyword but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be "JetBrains dotTrace 20xx.x" entry in Start Menu. If it doesn't exist, I'd recommend you to reinstall dotTrace or contact dotTrace support team.
But if you still want to open dotTrace manually, you need to run dotTrace64.exe file from %localappdata%\JetBrains\Installations\dotTrace11 folder (for 2017.3 version of dotTrace).

Comment: basically that localalldata path worked out...thanks